# Blurry Text on Printing in IE 9 and Google Chrome in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, printing, internet-explorer-9

I have problem with printing text using Internet Explore 9 and Chrome.
For IE9

I use printer EPSON PLQ-20M, and what I have noticed is that If I use IE 7, 
there is no problem but when I print it in IE 9 I got the blurry text. 
I have try to use style sheet to change the font, color, and size but I still cannot solve the problem.

For Chrome

On Chrome we have 2 big problem

1- blur text as IE9

2- we can not Re-set page setup.
(page setup is always reset to default when we re-open browser page. )

Please help us to check with this problem as attachment and send the correction to us soon.
If have any problem, please contact to us by address below:

E-mail: sengsetya168@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry editing fixed the font thickness issue for me perfectly, we can tune the font thickness/darkness by calibrating FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA  value to anywhere between 150 and 190 hexadecimal( 336 to 400 decimal )

- START -> RUN -> REGEDIT
- search for FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA by keying " Ctrl F " ( will automatically take us to CurrentUser\ControlPanel\Desktop path)
- double-click mouse on FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA enter anything between 150 and 190 hexadecimal.(the Lower the value, the thicker the fonts.)
- close the REGEDIT tool
- LOGOFF and then LOGON

Now all the fonts are very thick & very dark in Chrome Browser.

But before this, we must make sure that ClearType smoothing is enabled in Windows( controlPanel -> personalization -> appearance -> Effects -> ClearType smooth check [ ticked box ] )

```
     or  alternately in  RegEdit ...
```

FONTSMOOTHING=2

FONTSMOOTHINGTYPE=2

FONTSMOOTHINGORIENTATION=1  for LCD-screen, 0 for CRT-screen

( Note:   MicrosoftClearTypeTuner   minimum GAMMA value is 1000   maximum 2200 decimal,  can not  tune outside the limit,   hence the Registry tweak)

Comment: thank you very much for reply, it is ok for font size = 10pt but the big problem when font size = 8pt or 7pt it is still have blur text